# search text after one element and replace it in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How I do search one string and replace it with `""`?

Example:

```
<div id="test">
  <span>test</span>
</div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ""
</script>
```

I want find `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ""` and replaced it with `""`.

**Important:** I'm using this code in other files of the website so just want remove this code after `<div id="test">`.

Thank You...

Comment: What is your final goal? Do you want to do this in the client or in the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search and replace character from a string then use it.

**javascript with regular expression**

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var res = str.replace(/blue/g, " ");
```

**Output**

```
Mr has a blue house and a blue car
```

But if you want to do it for recursive then use this:

**javascript code**

```
var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var res = str.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
```

**output**

```
Mr has a house and a car
```

For more details: [visit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)